# Cannot generate HTML file from cppcheck.xml on linux

Tags: html, jenkins, cppcheck, html-reports-jenkins

I am trying to generate HTML file from the cppcheck.xml file. But i keep getting the following error : -bash: htmlreport/cppcheck-htmlreport: No such file or directory

I have installed the cppcheck and the htmlreport/cppcheck-htmlreport is also added to /usr/bin. I dont know what to do next. I cant find anythong related to this error on the internet.

I have to publish the cppcheck.xml on the jenkins UI. But the job i have is a multibranch pipeline and it doesnt support the cppcheck plugin. So I am left with no other option but to convert the cppcheck.xml to html and then publish that on the jenkins. This is also now getting error. Please tell how i should proceed further.

Comment: Do you have python installed? cppcheck-htmlreport is a python script. Check with strace what is causing the error